# ZeroMQ: Which socket types for arbitrary communication between exactly 2 peers?

Tags: sockets, zeromq, distributed-system

I'm using 0MQ to let multiple processes talk to each other (IPC sockets, but should also work via TCP across different nodes). My code is similar to a client/server pattern, but REQ/REP sockets are not enough. Here is a sample conversation. See below for further details.

| Process A | Process B |
| --- | --- |
| open socket | not started |
| start process B | - |
| - | open socket, connect to A |
| - | send hello (successful start, socket information) |
| request work | - |
| - | do work |
| - | send response (work result 1) |
| - | send response (work result 2) |
| - | send unsolicited message |
| - | send response (work finished) |
| request termination | - |

Actually, A is (even though doing all the requests) closer to be the server component, since it is constantly running. Based on external triggers, A starts a sort of plugin process B.

- Every request needs to be answered by a `finished` response. Before that, N (between 0 and an arbitrary upper bound) responses can be sent from B.
- A new request can be sent from A even when the current request is still ongoing (no `finished` message received). If relevant, the code could be updated to buffer the requests.
- B sends an initial message which is not preceded by a request from A.
- B can send other messages (logging) anywhere in between, also not preceded by a request.
- Optional: A single socket in A should handle multiple plugin processes B, C, D...

A DEALER/ROUTER combination would probably match all requirements, but might be a bit too much. Process B will only ever connect to a single peer. And without the optional requirement above, the same would be true for process A as well. So I'm a bit hesitant to use DEALER and ROUTER sockets which are both able to handle multiple peers.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Q: what language(s) are you programming your app in?  Q: What platform(s) is it running under?

Comment: A will be a C++ app, B a Python app. On Linux.

Comment: If the communication is not strictly REQ/REP, ROUTER/DEALER is a more flexible alternative. Another option is to use not one set of sockets but two sets, for example PUSH/PULL for A-to-B and PULL/PUSH for B-to-A.